# Angular: Call a TS function when clicking a href in the message of a bootbox

Tags: angular, typescript, bootbox

I'm writing an Angular app and use BootBox to show popups. How can I trigger the function "retrieveTransferTeam" by clicking the href in the BootBox popup in the code below?. **I don't want to use button and callback in bootbox**.

_ HTML file: when the button is click, it will show the popup

```
<button (click)="transferLicenses()" class="btn btn">Transfer Licenses</button>
```

_ TS file:

```
transferLicenses(){
  let self = this;
  this.xferTeam = {};
  var popup = bootbox.confirm({
    title: "<span class='text-info'>Transfer Licenses</span>",
    message: `
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' (click)="retrieveTransferTeam()"> Retrieve</a>`,
    callback: function (result) {
      if (result) {
        // do something
      }
    }
  });
}

public retrieveTransferTeam(){
  console.log('hello');
}
```

Comment: I guess if you want to do something like this, you should pick a dialog library that gives you more freedom, preferably one that integrates with Angular out of the box.

Comment: @AllanJuan: Thank you. I'm newbie to Angular, so I didn't know that. I'll try that. However, I still hope someone will have a solution for this problem :D.